# Is Kanōsei a word?

Tags: translation, english-to-japanese, suffixes, nouns

I used Google translate and used the following translation provided by Google for 'possibly' in a letter I wrote

> 可能性もある *kanōsei mo aru*

Later I tried looking up the word in the dictionary, and couldn't find it. All I found was *kanō* 可能, the first two kanji, then looked up the third kanji *sei* 性 which means 'sex'. So that 可能性もある would translate into 'possibility of sex'? I've already sent the letter, without realizing. Will a Japanese person interpret 可能性もある like this?

Comment: No, 可能性 is definitely a word, and it means 'possibility'. Also you're interpreting the 'sex' there wrong - it's sex as in 'male and female', not as in 'intercourse'.

Comment: ～可能性もある is also a *very* common phrase meaning 'there is a possibility that ~'.

Comment: I want to think this is a joke, since searching for either the romaji spelling or the kanji in google result in obvious webpage hits for kanousei ;p

Comment: Yeah, seems like an attempt at a joke.

Answer (score 4):

Here ～性【せい】 is an ending similar to *-(i)ty*, *-ness*, *-cy*. For matters of illustration,

> 可能 + 性 = 可能性 ↔ *possible* + *-(i)ty* = *possibility*
>
> 安全 + 性 = 安全性 ↔ *secure* + *-(i)ty* = *security*

Indeed, 性 can also mean "gender" (although it cannot mean sexual intercourse), but this is not how 性 is used in 可能性, and no "Japanese person" would misunderstand this.

Comment: oh that's good then.  if the final character were separated with a space, would it be read differently?

Comment: There are no spaces in standard Japanese.